# Removing duplicates from an unsorted linked list returning incomplete output

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, logic

I have a problem in a question of removing duplicates from an unsorted linked list. My code is not returning the output as I need.

```
Node * removeDuplicates( Node *head) 
{
    Node *cur=head;
    Node *prev=NULL;
    Node *nextptr;
    while(cur!=NULL){
        nextptr=cur->next;
        cur->next=prev;
        prev=cur;
        cur=nextptr;
    }
    head=prev;
    Node *temp=head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL){
        if(temp->data=temp->next->data){
            temp->next=temp->next->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

The linked list given is `5->2->2->4->NULL`.
This is code for removing duplicates from an unsorted linked list. Its return type is a pointer. I am not getting required output. The required output is `5->2->4->NULL`, but my output coming is only `5`. Please help me with correct code.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You might want to [explain to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) why your code is undeniably correct. There is quite a bit more in that function than just removing duplicates.

Comment: What do you think `temp->data=temp->next->data` does?

Comment: You probably should [enable and address warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings) before asking for help. Your compiler wants to help you write bug-free code, and it responds faster than people on the Internet.

Comment: [One of the problems](https://godbolt.org/z/ccYEcMWPq).

Answer (score 1):

There are these issues:

- Instead of comparing data in the `if` statement, you are *assigning*. So change:

  ```
  if(temp->data=temp->next->data){
  ```

  to:

  ```
  if(temp->data==temp->next->data){
  ```
- When that comparison is false, nothing else happens in the loop's body, so the `while` loop will then get stuck. You should move the `temp` pointer. So add an `else` block:

  ```
  } else {
      temp = temp->next;
  }
  ```

Some other remarks:

- Don't compare/initialise pointers with `NULL`, but with `nullptr`
- The first part of your function reverses the list. This seems unrelated to the purpose of the function, so omit that.

Corrected:

```
Node * removeDuplicates( Node *head) {
    Node *temp=head;
    while (temp->next != nullptr) {
        if (temp->data == temp->next->data) {
            temp->next = temp->next->next;
        } else {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```